# paint() try-catch statement won't execute a function that accesses a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner, paint

Ok so I have a function called gitBits() and it runs through its code.  It contains a Scanner and a File.  The file 100% exists because I made it.  The function runs correctly if called from main() with the correct output.  However, when I go to paint() and call the function, it tells me that there is a FileNotFoundException.  To solve this, I put the called function into a try-catch statement and caught the exception.  My code executes without any errors, but the problem is that my function getBits()'s return value is never assigned to my array of ArrayLists, arrayArray.

```
public class bitmaps extends JApplet{
public void init(){
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
}

//This function reads from a bitmap file and stores the characters (0s and 1s) into arrayLists
public static ArrayList[] getBits() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File bitmapFile = new File("bitmap.bmp");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(bitmapFile);

    int numLines = 0;

    String readStrings = "";
    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Character> onesZeros = new ArrayList<Character>();

    do{
        readStrings = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(readStrings);
        stringArray.add(readStrings);
        numLines++;

        for(char ch: readStrings.toCharArray()){
            onesZeros.add(ch);
        }
    } while(reader.hasNextLine());

    System.out.println(onesZeros);

    reader.close();

    ArrayList[] arrayArray = {stringArray, onesZeros};

    return arrayArray;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);

    g.drawString("begin", 25, 25); //DRAWS THIS

    ArrayList[] arrayArray = new ArrayList[2]; //THIS IS FINE

    try{
        g.drawString("1", 50, 50); //DRAWS THIS
        arrayArray = getBits(); //DOESN'T EXECUTE THIS ASSIGNMENT
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

    }
    finally{
        g.drawString("end", 75, 75); //DRAWS THIS
    }

    //SOMETHING I TRIED EARLIER, DOESN'T WORK

    /*ArrayList[] arrayArray = getBits();

    ArrayList<String> bitLines = arrayArray[0];
    ArrayList<Character> onesZeros = arrayArray[1];
    int x = 0;*/

    /*for(char bit: onesZeros){
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }*/
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

}
}
```

So I throw the exception and everything, so everything should be fine.  I just don't understand why it won't be assigned to the return value of getBits();

Comment: Please tell me you're not trying to read a binary file with a character base reader...Also, don't use applets, start with a `JPanel` and add that to a instance of `JFrame`.

Comment: Your `main` method is defined as `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException` <- It's defined to throw `FileNotFound` exception.  `paint`, because you're overriding it, can be defined the same way, so you need to deal with it

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I throw the exception for paint like I did with main, I'd get an error saying I can't override the container.  And I'm eventually wanting to draw lines and pixels to the screen, which I don't think I can do without paint() and making it an applet.

Comment: Precisely, you need to `catch` and deal with the error, you are unable to propagate the error from `paint` like you are with `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an absolute path for `bitmap.bmp` instead of a relative one.
Also,

```
try
{
    g.drawString("1", 50, 50);
    arrayArray = getBits();
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{

}
finally
{
    g.drawString("end", 75, 75);
}
```

**should be**

```
try
{
    g.drawString("1", 50, 50);
    arrayArray = getBits();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    g.drawString("end", 75, 75);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This whole time in my getBits() function I was using my File object when I could've just put the absolute path for bitmap.bmp into Scanner.  I never thought this was a problem! Wow! Thanks so much (by the way I was able to remove my try catch since I made this change).

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the solution which solved your problem so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to throw FileNotFoundException on your program .please remove that line from paint method.Your program itself throws flienotfound exception object. 
 throw new FileNotFoundException(); please comment/remove this line

Answer (score 0):

What else did you expect? If `getBits` throws an exception the assignment will of course not be done.

The problem most likely is that `bitmap.bmp` is not in the current directory when you run the code in an applet context.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `throw new FileNotFoundException();` so:

```
try{
    g.drawString("1", 50, 50); //DRAWS THIS
    arrayArray = getBits(); //DOESN'T EXECUTE THIS ASSIGNMENT
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){

}
```

Otherwise, it'll be throwing that exception each time you call `paint()`.